# Is it safe to draw part of an Android bitmap onto itself with some overlap?

Tags: android

I tested this on my Motorola Droid, and it worked as intended.  However, I'm concerned that this might be:

1. Terribly inefficient.
2. Not guaranteed to work on all Android phones.

Code:

```
/* Create a simple 100 by 100 bitmap */
Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

/* Create a canvas with which to draw on my bitmap */
Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);

/* Draw a subset of my bitmap onto itself, with the source rectangle and destination rectangle overlapping */
Rect sourceRect = new Rect(10, 0, 99, 99);
Rect destRect = new Rect(0, 0, 89, 99);
myCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, sourceRect, destRect, null);
```

As I said, this seemed to work fine in my testing, but when performing bit blits on other platforms, I haven't always been able to guarantee that it's safe, memory and performance-wise, to copy one grpahics region to another when the source and destinations intersect.

I'd welcome any insight into this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be perfectly safe.
As for intersection - what could be wrong?
If you are copying to region which you have copy from then it depends on implementation including your code. Worst (actually best) scenario is when it is copied byte by byte and you will have prefect "zebra" replication of your region where strip is the difference between source and destination regions. 
However, since most IO operations even in memory are buffered then your zebra will probably have interference of buffer/strip discrepancy. Which could be a little funny because of buffer, strip size and actual location of the region in the memory.

In other words it may look like image in kaleidoscope but it's perfectly safe.